# How do I avoid getting two of the same arrays when using Math.random?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am playing around with a web app and ran into an issue with generating two different items and avoid getting the same item two times.

```
// ITEM 1
var item1 = [
  "i/itemname1.png",
  "i/itemname2.png",
  "i/itemname3.png"
];

var size = item1.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

function getItem1() {
    document.getElementById("item1").src = item1[x];
}
getItem1();

// ITEM 2
var item2 = [
  "i/itemname1.png",
  "i/itemname2.png",
  "i/itemname3.png"
];

var size = item2.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

function getItem2() {
    document.getElementById("item2").src = item2[x];
}
getItem2();
```

With this code I got a chance to get two of the same items.
I need a solution to avoid this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the index you've already generated.

```
// ITEM 1
var item1 = [
  "i/itemname1.png",
  "i/itemname2.png",
  "i/itemname3.png"
];

var size = item1.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

function getItem1() {
    document.getElementById("item1").src = item1[x];
}
getItem1();

// ITEM 2
var item2 = [
  "i/itemname1.png",
  "i/itemname2.png",
  "i/itemname3.png"
];

// changes start here:
size = item2.length
var x2 = Math.floor((size-1)*Math.random())
if (x2 >= x) x2++ // skip `x`

function getItem2() {
    document.getElementById("item2").src = item2[x2]; // <-- x2 here, not x
}
getItem2();
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and give me an example using my code?

Comment: The part `if (x2 >= x) x2++` doesn't seem sensible. If *x* is 2 and *x2* is also 2 (pretty good odds at 1:3 or 1:9 overall) then it will set *x2* to 3, and `items[3]` is undefined.

Comment: @RobG `x2` will not ever be 2, since `(size-1)` is 2 and `Math.random()` will never return `1.0`

Comment: @JacobKrall—Ok, but if *x* and *x2* are 1, then you are biasing *x2* to 2, when it should go to 0 or 2 with equal chance. Also, if *x* is 0 and *x2* is 1, then *x2* is changed to 2. Not really random.

Comment: No. If `x` is 1, then there is a 50% chance of `x2` being 0 and a 50% chance of `x2` being 1, which then gets incremented to 2.

Comment: If `x` is 0, and `x2` is 1, then `x2` is changed to 2. But if `x2` is 0, it's changed to 1. Still 50-50.

Comment: Cool. I think this summarises why answers should include explanations of how they work, not just code. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

```
n = array.length

1. Get an item (randomly) from the array (from 0 to n) -> index1.
2. Swap the items in index1 with n
3. n = n - 1
4. Get an item (randomly) from the array (from 0 to n) -> index2.
```

The two items will be different

Answer (score 1):

If you slice the array (to create a duplicate array within the scope of function), generate a random number and splice the array until you have two unquie items.

```
function getRandom(listOfThings,numberOfItems){
    let newarray = listOfThings.slice();
    let returnarray = [];
    for(let count=1;count<numberOfItems;count++){
        let size = newarray.length
        let x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
        returnarray.push(newarray.splice(x-1,1));
     }
     return returnarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to generate it again if they are the same

```
function generateRandomExcept(except, len, tries) { 
    if(tries >= len) 
        return null; 
    tries++;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    return (num === except) ? generateRandom(min, max) : num;
}
```

Comment: If you're soooooo unlucky this will go on forever hhhhhhh

Comment: You can monitor number of attempts . Or you can remove the generated element from the 2nd array. It will take times if your array has many elements. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = [
  'i/itemname1.png',
  'i/itemname2.png',
  'i/itemname3.png'
];

/**
 * @param {Number} arr
 * @param {Number} n
 * @returns {Array} of length of n.
 */
function getRandomFromArray(arr, n) {
  // Getting a copy of an array.
  arr = arr.slice();
  // Removing elements from the array as long as there are not only required n elements left.
  while(arr.length > n) {
    // Randomly removing element from the array.
    arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
  }
  return arr;
}

// Returns an array consisting of 2 elements.
getRandomFromArray(items, 2);
```